# Problems updating Android Development Tools Bundle to version 22

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

**Problems:**
1) When ADT/ Eclipse starts, it stills show version 21
[image: eclipse start]

2) When I check "About ADT", it doesn't show the version number like it used to do for version 21
[image: About ADT]

3) When I clicked on "Installation details" I could see both ADT version 21 and 22 installed. It should be that way, right?
[image: Installation details]

4) The logo now changes to Eclipse logo instead of ADT logo

**How I updated my ADT bundle:**
(I did not install ADT plugin for existing Eclipse but download ADT bundle from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and used it ever since)

First, I updated SDK to version 22 using SDK manager, note that I updated and installed both

- Android SDK Platform-tools 17
- Android SDK Built-tools 17

Second, I updated the ADT following [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting)

What should I do now?

Answer (score 2):

Updating via Eclipse itself is often pretty buggy.
You might want to simply download the new version from the developer website and delete the old one after you make sure that everything works well with 22.

Comment: that's not ideal at all but you get less headaches that way..  Alternatively, you can also migrate to Android Studio that at least have a reliable update mechanism. But if you are very comfortable with Eclipse, it may not be worth it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I had the exact same outcome (captured in the screenshots) as fuzzy bee when I updated via Eclipse's Android SDK manager. Deleting the entire Eclipse ADT and downloading the updated ADT from Google's website fixed the problem on the first attempt.

Comment: I didn't delete my old ADT but just downloaded the new ADT and import the project I was working on